# The function $m: C^{\infty}(M) \times C^{\infty}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$ $m(f,g) = fg$ is $C^{\infty}$ bilinear ... so is it tensor like?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

The function $m: C^{\infty}(M) \times C^{\infty}(M)  \to C^{\infty}(M)$ $m(f,g) = fg$ is $C^{\infty}$ linear in both components... so is it a tensor of some kind? I know (I think) it is not a multilinear map from $X(TM) \times ... X(TM) \times X(TM^*) \times... X(TM^*)$, so it isn't a tensor in the usual sense.

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this. I am confused because I saw the Leibniz rule (say for a (1,1) tensor) for connections presented as $\nabla_X(T(\omega,Y)) = \nabla_XT(\omega,Y) + T(\nabla_X \omega,Y) + T(\omega, \nabla Y)$... and I was trying to understand how the usual Leibniz rule followed from this.

I'm confused...

For some affine connection $\nabla$, is $\nabla_{v} m = 0$ since multiplication is a "constant" operation? (Not that $\nabla_{v} m$ has any immediate meaning to me...)

Thanks!

Edit: (The Leibniz rule for covariant derivatives I am familiar with follows without from this definition after a long computation using the definition ($T \otimes S(...) = T(...)S(...)$). This is not exactly an answer to the question I asked, but it does resolve the origin of my confusion.)

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing the tensor product of vector spaces (or modules, etc.) with a tensor on a manifold. In the latter sense, a tensor of type $(p, q)$ on a manifold $X$ is a (smooth, etc. as desired) section of the bundle $TX^{\otimes p}\otimes T^*\!X^{\otimes q} \to X$. Since $T\mathbb{R}^n, T^*\mathbb{R}^n$ are trivial, we can identify the space of (smooth) tensors of type $(p, q)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a tensor product of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but that's not true over an arbitrary manifold.

Comment: @anomaly I think I understand what you are saying, but since my question is a local one I may as well assume that my manifold is $R^n$...

Comment: It is indeed. (The tensor algebra has a unit!) So in fact $C^\infty(M)$ are $(0,0)$ tensors, if you wish to think of it this way.  Your map $m$ is just a special case of the tensorial map taking a $(p,q)$ tensor and a $(p',q')$ tensor and giving a $(p+p',q+q')$ tensor, when $p=p'=q=q'=0$.

Comment: @AreaMan: Right (that comment was also before the edit). As was pointed out above, the spaces of sections $\Gamma(TX), \Gamma(T^*X)$ are $C^\infty(X)$ modules, and so a type $(0, 0)$ tensor is just an element of $C^\infty(X)\otimes C^\infty(X) = C^\infty(X)$ itself. The map $m$ you give is just that latter identification $f\otimes_{C^\infty(X)} g \to fg$.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill So, it is not absurd to take the covariant derivative of $m$? Can I conclude that it is zero without proving the usual Leibniz rule from the given one by a long computation?

Comment: @AreaMan: it is not "absurd" per se, but I don't see what is gained by thinking it that way.  Rather than thinking of $m$ as a multiplication, I like to think of it as the action of $C^\infty(M)$ on the module of tensor fields of type $(0,0)$, which just happens to isomorphic to $C^\infty(M)$.  One of the defining properties of any (Koszul) connection is $\nabla_X(f T) = X(f) T + f \nabla_X T$ for any tensor $T$ and one way to interpret this is to say that the action of $C^\infty(M)$ on the module of tensor fields is parallel.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Is saying that the action of $C^{\infty}(M)$ is parallel not the same thing as saying that $\nabla m =0$?

Comment: @AreaMan: Indeed it is.